# How do you say "This souvenir is from X" where X is a person or a place?

Tags: word-choice

Would it be correct to say

> これは日本のお[土産]{みやげ}です

to say that 'this souvenir is from Japan'? And if so, can the same form be used to say it's a present from a friend? For example

> これはよしさんのお土産です

as in 'this is a souvenir from Yoshi' (given to me by Yoshi)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one you can use (put stress on the 日本 and it emphasizes where the souvenir came from). With no stress it's "This is a Japanese souvenir."

For something which literally means that, you can use から.

> 'This souvenir is from Japan' 
>   これは日本**から**のお[土産]{みやげ}です。
>
> 'This is a souvenir from Yoshi'  
>   これはよしさん**から**のお土産です。

Bonus: これはよしさんから**もらった**お土産です。

Comment: Unless you are a kid, you would say いただいた ＞ もらった.

Comment: @非回答者 一般的にはそうなんですが、与える人との関係によるのではないでしょうか。部下や親しい友人なら、「いただいた」は使わないでしょう。（たしかに、そのような場合にはさん付けもしないけど。）

Answer (score 1):

Addition to the answer above.

To ask where some goods are produced you can say:

> "...は[何処]{どこ}[産]{さん}ですか?"

To ask where a person is from, you may ask (politely):

> "ご出身はどこですか?"

or rather informal form:

> "どこから来たのですか?"

Comment: そうですね。説明を入れた方が良いです。